# Wildfly deployment hook/event

Tags: deployment, hook, wildfly-8

Is there a way to create deployment hooks on Wildfly?

I need to be mailed after all deployments made in my server. Doesn't matter if the deployment is OK or not.

Comment: I have the same problem but I want to hook the deployment process before start on Wildfly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution: you need a custom log handler.

1. Create a class that extends java.util.logging.Handler;
2. Implement the publish(LogRecord) method. This method is called for each log entry;
3. Generate a .jar file;
4. Put it inside the folder "modules//main/";
5. In Wildfly 8.2 admin area, access Configuration/Core/Logging/Handler/Custom page. Wildfly must be rebooted;
6. Add a new Handler with your class information;
7. Go back to "Root Logger/Handler" page and add the new Handler.

That's all.